# html5 getUserMedia en http

Tags: html5, http

Se puede obtener la camara del usuario sin usuar un server https?

{name: "PermissionDeniedError", message: ""Only secure origins are allowed (see: https://www.chromium.org/Home/chromium-security/prefer-secure-origins-for-powerful-new-features)."
}